# Converting String to Double -- Loses Precision

Tags: c++, string, double

I am having trouble converting a string to a double. I am given a string with lat/long coordinates in the format of `33.9425/N 118.4081/W`

I first call my function `trimLastChar(std::string& input)` twice, which will remove the the North, South, East, West characters and then the forward slash. This function correctly returns `33.9425` and `118.4081` respectfully as a `std::string`.

I am using the following code to convert my `std::string` to a `double`...however the problem is, the conversion losses precision -- I suspect it gets rounded?.

```
// Location In String is what trimLastChar returns
std::stringstream stream(locationInString);
std::cout << "DEBUG: before: " << locationInString << " ";
// output is a double* output = new double passed by reference to my function
stream >> output;
std::cout << output << std::endl;
```

The output in this case would produce:

```
33.9425 
118.408
```

As you notice, the correct value should be `118.4081` but the 1 is missing...

Any ideas how to fix? Or more important, why is this happening?

Comment: ...you should check your output format, I'd guess this is just a formatting problem on cout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The precision wasn't lost on input. It's being lost on output.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
int main()
{
  double v = 118.4081;
  cout << v << endl;
  cout.precision(10);
  cout << v << endl;
}
```

outputs:

```
$ g++ -Wall x.cpp && ./a.out
118.408
118.4081
$
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably have more digits than the output shows. By default, only a small number of digits is shown, you need to use [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) to see more digits. Try

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << output << std::endl;
```